# Slice juggling in golang

Tags: pointers, go, slice

To be short, here is a deal: 
http://play.golang.org/p/ePiZcFfPZP

---

If I use commented lines, everything works, but there is no
any control on allocation sizes `(cap)`, so the slices,
if I got it correct, realloc every time they exceed their limit
and moreover, they start with zero capacity.

Passing a reference of `newSlice` in `setSlice()` don't work too.

So, I need ideomatic, elegant, go-ish method to do the job.

---

Thanks in advance, at least for attention and your time.

<s>UPD: 
solution was to make `SLICE` and `STASH` `*[]byte` typed

and make assigns to them like:</s>

```
var slicePtr *[]byte
tmp := make([]byte, 256)
slicePtr = &tmp // Tmp is needed because we can't take adress of make() rval.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, what are you trying to achieve? `s := make([]byte, 0, 5); len(s) == 0; cap(s) == 5`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include your code here if you wan to get any help, most people won't even click your external link. Also be sure to review http://stackoverflow.com/help on how to make a proper question

Comment: It would appear the OP is struggling with references. The `setSlice` function is supposed to flip the global `SLICE` reference to the newly created slice within the `main` function.

Comment: @Simon yeah but what is the goal, I mean he already figured out how to do it with the commented lines.

Comment: Not really it was a way to go with `new`.
Figured out a felt 'about ok` solution.
Seems like I was way too sleepy and hurry when asking a question. My apologize.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov if you solved the problem, you should post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

var SLICE, STASH []byte

func init() {
    SLICE = make([]byte, 0, 5)
}

func setSlice(slice []byte) {
    STASH = SLICE
    SLICE = slice
}

func restoreSlice() {
    SLICE = STASH
}

func appendToSlice(parts ...byte) []byte {
    SLICE = append(SLICE, parts...)
    return SLICE
}

func main() {
    appendToSlice('f', 'o', 'o')
    fmt.Printf("Everything is fine: {'%s'}\n", SLICE)

    newSlice := make([]byte, 0, 5)
    setSlice(newSlice)

    newSlice = appendToSlice('b', 'a', 'r')
    fmt.Printf("Bar? No! {'%s'}\n", newSlice) // <- I need "bar" appear in newSlice.
    fmt.Printf("Bar is here: {'%s'}\n", SLICE)

    restoreSlice()
    fmt.Printf("Back to origin. {'%s'}\n", SLICE)
}
```

Output:

```
Everything is fine: {'foo'}
Bar? No! {'bar'}
Bar is here: {'bar'}
Back to origin. {'foo'}
```

Like the Go `append` built-in function, your `appendToSlice` function needs to return the result of the append.

```
func appendToSlice(parts ...byte) []byte {
    SLICE = append(SLICE, parts...)
    return SLICE
}
```

and

```
newSlice = appendToSlice('b', 'a', 'r')
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The built-in functions append and copy assist in common slice
>   operations. For both functions, the result is independent of whether
>   the memory referenced by the arguments overlaps.
>
> The variadic function append appends zero or more values x to s of
>   type S, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type S.
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise,
>   append re-uses the underlying array.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> var b []byte
> b = append(b, "bar"...)    // append string contents; b == []byte{'b', 'a', 'r' }
> ```